# Creating maps.fld file of protein for AutoDock GPU

Tags: public-databases, docking

I want to use [AutoDock GPU](https://github.com/ccsb-scripps/AutoDock-GPU), which accepts protein.maps.fld and ligand.pdbqt files.

Since I am performing high throughput virtual screening, shall I just load protein AutoDockTools and create protein.maps.fld file, which I can use in my command line run of AutoDock GPU run?

I have 1 million ligands in my screening library, so can't repeat the above procedure on all ligands, or shall I just pick a ligand that contains all types of atoms a ligand can have in that ligand library and produce protein.maps.fld based upon that ligand along with the given protein?